# Convex combinations sequence question

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $a_0,a_1,\beta$ be given with $0<\beta<1$ Let the sequence be defined by

$a_{n+2} = \beta a_{n+1} + (1-\beta)a_n$ for $n\geq0$
Show that $\{a_n\}$ converges and find its limit..

How to find this? 
I got lost when i tried second order difference equation...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we can write it in two ways as
$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=(\beta-1)(a_{n+1}-a_n)$$
$$a_{n+2}-(\beta-1)a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-(\beta-1)a_n,$$
we have
$$a_{n+1}-a_n=(\beta-1)^n(a_1-a_0)$$
$$a_{n+1}-(\beta-1)a_{n}=a_1-(\beta-1)a_0.$$
Hence, substracting the latter from the former gives you
$$a_n=\frac{(\beta-1)-(\beta-1)^n}{\beta-2}a_0+\frac{(\beta-1)^n-1}{\beta-2}a_1.$$
Hence, noting that $(\beta-1)^n\to 0\ (n\to\infty)$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\frac{\beta-1}{\beta-2}a_0-\frac{1}{\beta-2}a_1=\frac{a_1+(1-\beta)a_0}{2-\beta}=\frac{\color{red}{1}\cdot a_1+\color{blue}{(1-\beta)}\cdot a_0}{\color{red}{1}+\color{blue}{(1-\beta)}}.$$

Comment: If $\beta\in(0,1)$, then you should get an answer between $a_0$ and $a_1$.  I think the denominator should be $\beta-2$.

Comment: @Michael: You are right! Thank you for pointing it out. I edited it.